# Node/Express/Jade - How can I configure dev/production URLs

Tags: node.js, express, configuration, pug, base-url

I'd like to configure different URLs for my production and dev environments that can be passed into my Jade templates. I have a couple links to subdomains, so I need the full URL. I don't want to hardcode the URL into the template. Can I pass the full url into the template and have the url specified in a configurable based on which environment the app is running in?

I have this in my app:

```
app.configure('production', function(){

});

app.configure('development', function(){

});
```

But I'm not sure what the contents of `configure()` should be.

Once I have that configured, how can I access that from my routes file? Will those configurations be available to all files?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [app.locals](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.locals)

Comment: @laggingreflex Yes! That's exactly what I ended up finding. Feel free to add that as an answer if you'd like a check mark :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app.locals` lets you pass variables from your app to jade template. So you could do something like

```
app.configure('production', function(){
    app.locals.URLs = {
        resource1: '/production/resource1/url',
        resource2: '/production/resource2/url',
    }
});
app.configure('development', function(){
    app.locals.URLs = {
        resource1: '/development/resource1/url',
        resource2: '/development/resource2/url',
    }
});
```

And so you'll have access to the same variable which you can use in your template

```
script(src="#{URLs.resource1}")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you export the app variable, you can use app.get() to get the configuration by requiring that file..